# pagination sql query syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort my posts in my discussion board by date.  Here is my code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} 
LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit} 
ORDER BY datetime ASC");
```

Is there anything syntactically wrong with this?  If not, what else could be wrong?  Basically what is happening, is that the results are not showing up.  I remove the Order by, and it works (but of course it's not sorted...)

Comment: Are you sure your field is called "datetime"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Order by should go before limit:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} 
ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} 
ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit} ");
```

Answer (score 1):

May be a bit too late, but mySQL provides OFFSET key word that is very useful...especially for pagination

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {offset}
```

if 10 records per page is what you are looking for and you want to show records on page 2 i.e. records 11-20 your query will look like:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

REF: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm